# No Overload for 'MouseDoubleClick method' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler'

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, events, overloading

I have created an event MouseDoubleClick on a ListBoxItem, like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem content="Ajouts" Name="Ajouts" MouseDoubleClick="Ajout_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

The event Double Click perform an "Select From Where" on the Table Resultat made with LinQ, like this:

```
private void Ajout_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e, DBSet<Resultat> res)
{
    var add = from a in res
              where a.Remarque.Equals("Ajoute")
              select new { a.Groupe_D_alerte, a.Remarque }
}
```

I have got the error

> No overload for 'Ajout_MouseDoubleClick' matches delegate
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler'

I have the object sender, I have the same error if I replace `MouseButtonEventArgs` with `System.EventArgs` or `EventArgs`, the error is detected on xaml side.

Comment: remove the  DBSet<Resultat> res from the arguments

Comment: Okay, but If I do this, how can I set on which base I do the request? I mean. If I do this, res doesn't mean nothing, and if I replace it with `var add = from a in DbSet<Resultat>`, VS tell me It's a Type and I use it as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MouseButtonEventHandler delegate can only "point" to methods that match its signature

```
public delegate void MouseButtonEventHandler(Object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need that DbSet you must use another method to get it(a private field or something else)

```
private void Ajout_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e, )
{
    DBSet<Resultat> res=YourDbContext.Resultats;
    var add = from a in res
          where a.Remarque.Equals("Ajoute")
          select new { a.Groupe_D_alerte, a.Remarque }
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll look for an other way to call my DbSet.

Comment: I'll acerpt your answer as soon as I can, It's perfect. Thanks!